# Pattern for very slow DB Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, caching

I am building an Asp.net MVC site where I have a fast dedicated server for the web app but the database is stored in a very busy Ms Sql Server used by many other applications.

Also if the web server is very fast, the application response time is slow mainly for the slow response from the db server.

I cannot change the db server as all data entered in the web application needs to arrive there at the end (for backup reasons).

The database is used only from the webapp and I would like to find a cache mechanism where all the data is cached on the web server and the updates are sent to the db asynchronously.

It is not important for me to have an immediate correspondence between read  db data and inserted data: think like reading questions on StackOverflow and new inserted questions that are not necessary to show up immediately after insertion).

I thought to build an in between WCF service that would exchange and sync the data between the slow db server and a local one (may be an Sqllite or an SqlExpress one).

What would be the best pattern for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your bottleneck? Reading data or Writing data?

If you are concerning about reading data, using a memory based data caching machanism like [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) would be a performance booster, As of most of the mainstream and biggest web sites doing so. [Scaling facebook hi5 with memcached](http://www.skrenta.com/2007/05/scaling_facebook_hi5_with_memc.html) is a good read. Also implementing application side page caches would drop queries made by the application triggering lower db load and better response time. But this will not have much effect on database servers load as your database have some other heavy users.

If writing data is the bottleneck, implementing some kind of asyncronyous middleware storage service seems like a necessity. If you have fast and slow response timed data storage on the frontend server, going with a lightweight database storage like mysql or postgresql (Maybe not that lightweight ;) ) and using your real database as an slave replication server for your site is a good choise for you.

Comment: If the bottleneck is writing, then you need to know whether the DB server can keep up with the web app over the course of a day.  If not, then the DB server is just never going to scale with you.  If it can, then you're in with a chance.  But why is the DB machine so slow?  Worry about that!

Comment: That's the real matter. Why db is not keeping up with the webapp? In need of better hardware? Needing load balancing? In real life there are some situations that you don't have any chance to fix. That's where workarounds come in. Sys admining is an art that deals with these irrational situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what you are already considering. Use another database for the application and only use the current one for backup-purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once, and we decided to go for a combination of data warehousing (i.e. pulling data from the database every once in a while and storing this in a separate read-only database) and message queuing via a Windows service (for the updates.)

This worked surprisingly well, because MSMQ ensured reliable message delivery (updates weren't lost) and the data warehousing made sure that data was available in a local database.

It still will depend on a few factors though. If you have tons of data to transfer to your web application it might take some time to rebuild the warehouse and you might need to consider data replication or transaction log shipping. Also, changes are not visible until the warehouse is rebuilt and the messages are processed.

On the other hand, this solution is scalable and can be relatively easy to implement. (You can use integration services to pull the data to the warehouse for example and use a BL layer for processing changes.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many replication techniques that should give you proper results. By installing a  SQL Server instance on the 'web' side of your configuration, you'll have the choice between:

- Making snapshot replications from the web side (publisher) to the database-server side (suscriber). You'll need a paid version of SQLServer on the web server. I have never worked on this kind of configuration but it might use a lot of the web server ressources at scheduled synchronization times
- Making merge (or transactional if requested) replication between the database-server side (publisher) and web side(suscriber). You can then use the free version of MS-SQL Server and schedule the synchronization process to run according to your tolerance for potential loss of data if the web server goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could improve it adding a MDF file in your Web side instead dealing with the Sever in other IP...

Just add an [SQL 2008 Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) file and try, as long as you don't pass 4Gb of data you will be ok, of course there are more restrictions but, just for the speed of it, why not trying?

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the network switches involved. If the DB server is talking to a number of web servers then it may be being constrained by the network connection speed. If they are only connected via a 100mb network switch then you may want to look at upgrading that too.

Answer (score 0):

the WCF service would be a very poor engineering solution to this problem - why make your own when you can use the standard SQLServer connectivity mechanisms to ensure data is transferred correctly. Log shipping will send the data across at selected intervals.

This way, you get the fast local sql server, and the data is preserved correctly in the slow backup server.

You should investigate the slow sql server though, the performance problem could be nothing to do with its load, and more to do with the queries and indexes you're asking it to work with.